# org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set, at table: USERS, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(invoices)]

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations

I have a problem that Hibernate is unable to determine the type for Set at the table USERS.
I am trying to create a foreign key of table INVOICES through one-to-many relationship. One User can generate many Invoices.
My User.java is given below.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USERS")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name="User_Id",nullable=false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer user_id;


    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="Address")
    private String address;

    @Column(name="Designation")
    private String designation;


    private Set<Invoice> invoices;

    /*@OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="Rec_Invoice_ID", nullable=false)
    private Set<RecurringInvoice> recurring_invoices;*/
```

I am trying to use INVOICE-ID as foreign key in USERS table. 
I am following the instructions given here 
[Hibernate: Annotation one-to-many (foreign-key)](http://tadtech.blogspot.in/2007/09/hibernate-annotation-one-to-many.html)

```
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="INVOICE_ID", nullable=false)
    public Set<Invoice> getInvoices() {
        return invoices;
    }

    public void setInvoices(Set<Invoice> invoices) {
        this.invoices = invoices;
    }

/*   public Set<RecurringInvoice> getRecurring_invoices() {
        return recurring_invoices;
    }

    public void setRecurring_invoices(Set<RecurringInvoice> recurring_invoices) {
        this.recurring_invoices = recurring_invoices;
    }
*/
    // Getters and Setters
    public Integer getUser_id() {
        return user_id;
    }

    public void setUser_id(Integer user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getDesignation() {
        return designation;
    }

    public void setDesignation(String designation) {
        this.designation = designation;
    }

}
```

My Invoice.java is given below.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="INVOICES")
public class Invoice {


    private Integer invoice_id;

    @Column(name="Date_Created", nullable=false)
    private Timestamp dateCreated;

    @Column(name="DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;

    @Column(name="Total_Amount")
    private Double totalAmount;

    @Column(name="Tax_Amount")
    private Double taxAmount;

    @Column(name="Due_Date")
    private Timestamp dueDate;

    @Column(name="deleted")
    private boolean deleted;


    private InvoiceItemsDetails invoiceItemsDetails;


    private Client client;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="ID", nullable=false)
    public Client getClient() {
        return client;
    }

    public void setClient(Client client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    public Date getDueDate() {
        return dueDate;
    }

    public void setDueDate(Timestamp dueDate) {
        this.dueDate = dueDate;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="INVOICE_ID", nullable=false, insertable=false,updatable=false)
    public Integer getInvoice_id() {
        return invoice_id;
    }

    public void setInvoice_id(Integer invoice_id) {
        this.invoice_id = invoice_id;
    }

    public Date getDateCreated() {
        return dateCreated;
    }

    public void setDateCreated(Timestamp dateCreated) {
        this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Double getTotalAmount() {
        return totalAmount;
    }

    public void setTotalAmount(Double totalAmount) {
        this.totalAmount = totalAmount;
    }

    public Double getTaxAmount() {
        return taxAmount;
    }

    public void setTaxAmount(Double taxAmount) {
        this.taxAmount = taxAmount;
    }

    public boolean isDeleted() {
        return deleted;
    }

    public void setDeleted(boolean deleted) {
        this.deleted = deleted;
    }

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="Invoice_Item_Detail_id", nullable=false)
    public InvoiceItemsDetails getInvoiceItemsDetails() {
        return invoiceItemsDetails;
    }

    public void setInvoiceItemsDetails(InvoiceItemsDetails invoiceItemsDetails) {
        this.invoiceItemsDetails = invoiceItemsDetails;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 103, accepted):

If I remember correctly, Hibernate doesn't let you mix and match annotation in conjunction with field / getter. If your `@Id` annotation is set over a field, all your mappings should follow fields. Try moving `@OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="INVOICE_ID", nullable=false)` from `getInvoices()` to `private Set<Invoice> invoices;` This pattern should be applied to your `Invoice` class as well

Comment: Hello orid, I have done what you said but now I am getting a new exception org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: net.impetus.dto.Invoice column: INVOICE_ID (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

Comment: That's because `invoice_id` field is also mapped with same column name: `@Column(name="INVOICE_ID"...` Change the FK column name to something such as `@OneToMany @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID", nullable=false) private Set<Invoice> invoices;`

Comment: Great answer -- solved the same problem I was having in my environment.

Comment: thanks , it helped me to resolve issue in my code, +1

Comment: Brilliant.  How pedantic though!

Comment: Thanks man, would have caused much pain had I not found this soon enough ! You could be looking for a lot of things before you try to define all your annotations on the same spot thinking it might cause troubles to mix up fields/getters...

Comment: @OriDar Thanks for this explanation, very helpful!