# org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E:(pos 8): Method call

Tags: spring, spring-webflow, spelevaluationexception

I want to display a list of data from data base on the home page but I get the following error

> org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E:(pos 8): Method call: Method listAnnonce() cannot be found on sujet.projet.collocation.domain.Annonce type at

#### User.java

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "utilisateur" )
public class UserEntity extends BaseEntity {

    // attribut

    @OneToMany( mappedBy = "annonceUser" )
    private List<Annonce>     annonce;

    public List<Annonce> getAnnonce() {
        return annonce;
    }

    public void setAnnonce( List<Annonce> annonce ) {
        this.annonce = annonce;
    } //getter setter
}
```

#### Interface.java

```
public List<Annonce> liste();
```

#### InterfaceImpl.java

```
public List<Annonce> liste() {

    return annonceDao.findAll();
}
```

#### main-flow.xml

```
 <var name="annonce" class="sujet.projet.collocation.domain.User"/>
 <view-state id="accueil" view="accueil.xhtml" model="annonce">
     <on-render>
         <evaluate expression="annonce.list()"/>
     </on-render>
     <transition on="toauthentification" to="authentification" />
 </view-state>
```

#### Annonce.java

```
@Entity 
@Table( name = "annonce" ) 
public class Annonce extends BaseEntity {

    //attribut

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn( name = "annonceUser" )
    private User        annonceUser;

    public User getAnnonceUser() {
        return annonceUser;
    }

    public void setAnnonceUser( User annonceUser ) {
        this.annonceUser = annonceUser;
    }
    //getter&setter 
}
```

Someone could help me or suggest me a solution?

Comment: But, does `listAnnonce()` exist in `Annonce.java` ?

Comment: now whene i add listAnnonce to Annonce.java I have this error : "Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: annonce,"

Comment: possible duplicate: 
[1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774198/how-to-make-this-tutorial-work-could-not-determine-type-for-java-util-list-) & 
[2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15849278/org-hibernate-mappingexception-could-not-determine-type-for-java-util-set-at)

Comment: Look at the two question links above, they seem to be helpful.

Comment: I still have the same error

Comment: What's the code of `Annonce.java`?

Comment: The current exception ?

Comment: ok now i put this code in File: main-flow.xml `<view-state id="accueil" view="accueil.xhtml" model="annonce" >
 <on-render>
     <evaluate expression="user.annonce" result-   type="java.util.ArrayList"/>
   </on-render>
 </view-state>`

Comment: and i have no exception but in the same time i have  No records found.

Comment: The problem disappeared so. What you're facing is another issue, just express it through another new question.