# Hibernate manyToOne mapping with multiple underscores not working

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to create a mapping in Hibernate on an Entity with ManyToOne relationship. I am trying this:

CampaignItemSlot class:

```
 package models;

 import java.sql.Timestamp;

 import javax.persistence.Column;
 import javax.persistence.Entity;
 import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
 import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
 import javax.persistence.Id;
 import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
 import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
 import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
 import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "campaign_item_slots")
public class CampaignItemSlot {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

@JoinColumn(name = "advert_slot_id")
@ManyToOne
private AdvertSlot advertSlot;

private boolean active;

private Timestamp date_created;

 private Timestamp date_updated;

 public CampaignItemSlot() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
 }
}
```

However I get this in the log file:

```
  Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing column: advertSlot_id in text_advertising.campaign_item_slots
```

This is my table SQL:

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `text_advertising`.`campaign_item_slots` (
  `id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   
  `campaign_item_id` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `advert_slot_id` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `active` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT TRUE,
  `date_created` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `date_updated` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_campaignitems_1_idx` (`campaign_item_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_campaignitems_2_idx` (`advert_slot_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_campaign_item_slots_1`
  FOREIGN KEY (`campaign_item_id`)
  REFERENCES `text_advertising`.`campaignitems` (`id`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_campaign_item_slots_2`
  FOREIGN KEY (`advert_slot_id`)
  REFERENCES `text_advertising`.`advert_slots` (`id`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
  ENGINE = InnoDB
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
  COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;
```

AdvertSlot class:

```
  package models;

  import java.sql.Timestamp;

  import javax.persistence.Entity;
  import javax.persistence.EnumType;
  import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
  import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
  import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
  import javax.persistence.Id;
  import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
  import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
  import javax.persistence.Table;

  @Entity
  @Table(name = "advert_slots")
  public class AdvertSlot {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

@ManyToOne
private Publication publication;

private String name;

private String description;

private boolean active;

private Timestamp date_created;

private Timestamp date_updated;

public AdvertSlot() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Publication getPublication() {
    return publication;
}

public void setPublication(Publication publication) {
    this.publication = publication;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public boolean isActive() {
    return active;
}

public void setActive(boolean active) {
    this.active = active;
}

public Timestamp getDate_created() {
    return date_created;
}

public void setDate_created(Timestamp date_created) {
    this.date_created = date_created;
}

public Timestamp getDate_updated() {
    return date_updated;
}

public void setDate_updated(Timestamp date_updated) {
    this.date_updated = date_updated;
}   
 }
```

Somehow Hibernate is not seeing my advert_slot_id, help please?

Comment: can you post `AdvertSlot`  class ?

Comment: Can you post the code of entity built on `campaign_item_slots` table?

Comment: Hi I have added CampaignItemSlot class

Comment: I want to understand relation. as far as i understand `AdvertSlot` has many `campaign_item_slots` am i rigth ?

Comment: Could you try to add getter/setter and move the annotation there?

Comment: @StanislavL now I get this error: Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: models.AdvertSlot, at table: campaign_item_slots, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(advertSlot)]

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15849278/org-hibernate-mappingexception-could-not-determine-type-for-java-util-set-at) could help you @lulu88 for last problem.

Comment: Did you have getter and setter for `advertSlot` before @StanislavL's suggestion? If no, try with getter and setter but leave the annotations on the field.

Comment: @PredragMaric that was the first thing. Missing getters/setters means problems of proxy creating. Could be the reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer here is to create a custom naming strategy by extending org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy and then referencing it via hibernate config: hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy

Here is an example:

```html
    @Override
    public  String foreignKeyColumnName(String propertyName, String propertyEntityName, String propertyTableName, String referencedColumnName) {
     String changed = CaseFormat.UPPER_CAMEL.to(CaseFormat.LOWER_UNDERSCORE, propertyName) + "_id";
     return changed;
    }
```

Comment: Well no, that's called a workaround. The solution is to fix Hibernate, by reporting the bug with a way of reproducing it.

Answer (score 1):

It will work.Try this way:

First table:

```
@Table(name = "buyer_city")
public class BuyerCity{

    //other fields
    .....

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="buyerCity", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<BuyerCityMapping> buyerCityMapping = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Second table:

```
@Table(name = "buyer_city_mapping")
public class BuyerCityMapping{

    //other fields

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonBackReference
    @JoinColumn(name = "buyer_city_id")
    private BuyerCity buyerCity;
}
```