# org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: at table: for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(plant)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I know this question have been asked [several  times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15849278/org-hibernate-mappingexception-could-not-determine-type-for-java-util-set-at) but, they didn't help me.
I have the following test:

```
public class PlantCatalogTests {
    @Autowired
    PlantInventoryEntryRepository plantRepo;

    @Test
    public void queryPlantCatalog() {
        assertThat(plantRepo.count(), is(14l)); 
    }
```

and here is **PlantInventoryEntryRepository**

```
@Repository
public interface PlantInventoryEntryRepository  extends JpaRepository<PlantInventoryEntry, Long> {}
```

As you see, this repository is based on the class **PlantInventoryEntry**

```
@Entity
@Data
public class PlantInventoryEntry {

      @Id
      @GeneratedValue
      Long id;

      @OneToOne
      PurchaseOrder plant_id;

      String name;
      String description;

      String price;   
}
```

PurchaseOrder  is another class, which i have one instance of it as an attribute in my **PlantInventoryEntry** class:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class PurchaseOrder {
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue
      Long id;

      List<PlantReservation> reservations;
      PlantInventoryEntry plant;

      LocalDate issueDate;
      LocalDate paymentSchedule;
      @Column(precision=8,scale=2)
      BigDecimal total;

      @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
      POStatus status;
      LocalDate startDate;
      LocalDate endDate;
    }
```

My main problem is that, when i run my test, i face with this error:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.example.models.PlantInventoryEntry, at table: purchase_order, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(plant)
```

How can i fix the error??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to identify the relationship by using a **@ManyToOne** or **@OneToOne** annotation on *PlantInventoryEntry* in *PurchaseOrder*, depending on what the actual relationship is between the entities.

**Edit:**  You most likely need to identify the relatationship between the List of *PlantReservation*s and *PurchaseOrder*, or you need to mark it as **@Transient** if its not managed by JPA.

```
@Entity
@Data
public class PurchaseOrder {
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue
      Long id;

      //  You need to set the mappedBy attribute to the field name
      //  of PurchaseOrder in PlantReservation
      //  Update: omit mappedBy if PurchaseOrder is not mapped in PlantReservation
      @OneToMany(mappedBy="order")
      List<PlantReservation> reservations;

      @ManyToOne
      PlantInventoryEntry plant;

      LocalDate issueDate;
      LocalDate paymentSchedule;
      @Column(precision=8,scale=2)
      BigDecimal total;

      @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
      POStatus status;
      LocalDate startDate;
      LocalDate endDate;
    }
```

Comment: Could you describe** mappedby="order" ** in the statement **@OneToMany(mappedBy="order")**?

Comment: Is the field mapped in both objects?  If so, you need to specify the mappedBy attribute like above.  If its only mapped in PurchaseOrder, you can omit it.  See the docs for more info  https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html