# Spring Boot ArrayList Validation

Tags: java, validation, jpa, arraylist, dto

I have the following incoming ArrayList (reduced down for clarity and example purposes).

```
[
   {
      "details1":
      {
        "firstname":"John", 
        "lastname":"Doe"
      },
      "details2":
      {
        "phone":"9999999999"        
      }
   }
   {
      "details1":
      {
        "firstname":"Jane", 
        "lastname":"Doe"
      },
      "details2":
      {
        "phone":"9999999999"
      }
   }
]
```

Object/Model for details1

```
@Data
public class details1{ 

    @Column(name="firstname")
    @NotBlank(message = "First Name is a required field.")
    public String firstname;

    @Column(name="lastname")
    @NotBlank(message = "Last Name is a required field.")
    public String lastname;
}
```

Object/Model for details2

```
@Data
public class details2{ 

    @Column(name="phone")
    @NotBlank(message = "Phone is a required field.")
    public String phone;
}
```

I would like `bindingresult` to show an error for first and last name as well as phone in the event they were blank.

It works if I send down just `details1` or `details2` and change `ArrayList<profiles> profiles` with `details1 details1`, as well as update the JPARepository with details1. However this only allows me to send 1 object.

```
@RestController
public class controller {

  @PostMapping("/v1/submit") 
  public void submit(@Valid @RequestBody ArrayList<profiles> profiles, BindingResult bindingresult) { }

    System.out.println(bindingresult)
}
```

Profiles Object/Model

```
@Data
@Entity
public class profiles{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id")
    public Long id;

    /* 

     I assume somewhere here I need to add a variable for the profile 
     Model/DTO and something to account for @Valid on said variable.

     Something similar to this
    
     // public List<Map<String, Map<String, String>>> profile
    
    */
    
    
    
}
```

Profiles Repository

```
@Repository
public interface profilesrepository extends JpaRepository<profiles, Long>{
    
}
```

Comment: By the way, on a side note, in Java, class names are PascalCased. So, e.g., your `public class profiles` would become: `public class Profiles`, your `public interface profilesrepository` would become: `public interface ProfilesRepository` etc.

Comment: Your JSON is erroneous at the moment, by the way. There is a comma missing in it. Can't edit that as edits require at least 6 characters to be written..................... If you can't find it, please use a JSON validation website to see where the comma is missing (or see last code snippet in my answer that contains it).

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of `@Valid` is correct. You must also annotate your controller class with `@Validated`. You can read the `@Validated` annotation documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/annotation/Validated.html).

If that doesn't work then also make sure you also have the `spring-boot-starter-validation` dependency. Latest  version of the dependency can be found [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-validation/2.3.4.RELEASE).

---

**Edit with additional explanation/examples:**

Your `profiles` class should look like this:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class profiles {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;
    
    @Valid
    private details1 details1;

    @Valid
    private details2 details2;
    

    public details1 getDetails1() {
        return details1;
    }

    public void setDetails1(details1 details1) {
        this.details1 = details1;
    }

    public details2 getDetails2() {
        return details2;
    }

    public void setDetails2(details2 details2) {
        this.details2 = details2;
    }
}
```

The `@Valid` annotation on top of the properties indicates that the corresponding values within it - that are annotated with a constraint validation annotation - are subject to constraint validation.

You then could receive a JSON that looks like the following:

```
[
    {
        "details1": 
        {
            "firstname": "John",
            "lastname": "Doe"
        },
        "details2":
        {
            "phone":"9999999999"
        }
    },
    {
        "details1":
        {
            "firstname":"Jane", 
            "lastname":"Doe"
        },
        "details2":
        {
            "phone":"9999999999"
        }
    }
]
```

If you have (some) control over the data that are being sent to your controller, then you could tweak the values (e.g. make a `firstname` an empty String) to see the constraint validation with the message specified in the `@NotBlank` in action. You can remove the `BindingResult bindingresult` from your controller method in this case.

Comment: Thanks @Troley, Understood with the PascalCased note. I guess my bigger question is within the profiles class do I need to add a variable for profile? I feel as though I am still missing a few things. I can easily add `@Validated` in, but that's included with the same dependency as `@Valid`, which works fine when sending a single object down. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: Oh yes, I totally overlooked that it's not `profile` but that it in fact is `profiles` that is being captured by the controller method. Yes, by the looks of it, your `profiles` class doesn't do any validation (I don't know for sure because I don't see the whole class). Your `profile` class, for example, does do validation of the `firstname` and `lastname` properties with the `@NotBlank` annotation (which indicated that the Strings might not be empty and not null). I'll edit my answer explaning this with an example on the `profiles` class.

Comment: Could you please explain the part why you can only send 1 object to the controller method? That object can also be a list of `profile`, right? In that case you could simply use `ArrayList<profile>`, right? I kind of missed that part in between the edits, sorry.

Comment: I think my over simplification of the code was making it a little confusing. I updated it to be a little more reflective of what I want to do. Let me know if that makes more sense now.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to look at this. Taking your suggestions into account, both require reformat of the JSON coming down. Simply put, in the final solution I can't change the incoming format.

Comment: Sorry it took a bit longer. Went to sleep yesterday after my last post. Edited the answer now to match your data.

Comment: no worries. I appreciate you helping out, I am still trying to run this thing down. I put in what you suggested, but getting the following when trying to compile. `Could not determine type for: com.demo.v1.tenantapplications.domain.details1, at table: profiles, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(details1)]`

Comment: Hm yeah, that is no longer a validation issue, but more of a Hibernate relationships mapping issue. What you probably would want to read more about is "Hibernate relationships mapping". This article could get you started pretty well in my opinion: https://thorben-janssen.com/ultimate-guide-association-mappings-jpa-hibernate/ . In addition to that, this old SO answered question also seems to be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35581630/7804385 .